# Email Tracking using "image" method won't work with Gmail

Tags: php, html, image, email, server

If I'm not being clear about anything let me know... I'm new to SO.

I'm having troubles getting Gmail to approve of my image URL that will activate my PHP script to track when people open my emails.

Gmail only allows me to "insert" photos that are specifically image files, such as png or jpg files. I have tried using a file-include mechanism:
**http://www.example.com/?file=image.png** with a two-line PHP script that includes the png file and then writes to a log all the tracking info. However, I have found this doesn't work since I'm technically referencing index.php in the URL.

I have also tried **http://www.example.com/script.php** where script.php would look like this:

```
<img src=image.png>
<?php
// write "Someone viewed your mail" in logs
?>
```

This doesn't work either because I'm still referencing a PHP file.

I'm using the Insert Photo > Web Address feature in Gmail... should I be inserting the file differently to fix my problem? I need to find a way to directly reference an image file on my server but also activate the PHP script.

Any ideas? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: im confused as what you are doing, its a standard approach to link to a hosted image file for counting opens. you should just and an `<img src="http://ezample.com/track.jpg">` in the email. can you include your mail sending code and mail body contents

Comment: @tim what do you mean by "mail sending code". I'm sort of inexperienced with anything revolving around emails, sorry...!

Comment: you have php code sending the email, need to see that.

Comment: I was aiming for simply loading up the gmail site and composing the email; inserting a photo on the compose menu. So you're saying this can only be done with sending the emails via code? I can make a python program to do this if thats the case...

Comment: I've never herd of any one adding a link manually like that, the technique is usually used with your mail sending application.

Comment: @tim I figured out that I can do this with Thunderbird, and address my page as so: <img src="www.example.com/script.php">

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I can do this with **Thunderbird**:

**Write --> Insert --> HTML**

In the HTML box:

```
<img src="www.mysite.com/script.php">
```

Hopes this helps anyone who had my problem